# PHP/MySQL text field search by condition

Tags: php, mysql, lambda

I have **product search page** in php/mysql. I have text field named **price** in table **products**. I need to be able to search products in mysql table **using expressions** like this:

1. => 35 AND <= 45
2. < 200
3. >= 200 OR 45
4. // etc

Is this prossible to leave this functionality to user and **safely/fast** search products by price, using user-friendly expressions ?

I just don't know where to begin. 
Is [create_function](http://php.net/create_function) something I'm looking for ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to provide the user with an interface to allow them to build up conditions for their query. You then use this data to programmatically build up your SQL query appropriately (being wary of SQL injection).

Also ensure you have an index on the price column to ensure MySQL can run the query quickly.

Comment: but how do i parse this expressions ? so many possible ways to write an expression: AND, OR, (), ...

Comment: You need to build your interface to limit the user's choices. I'd suggest a text box for the price, a dropdown with options for `=`, `>=`, `<=`, and then if they add a second condition you also provide another dropdown with an AND/OR option.

Comment: nail it down to the minimum you can get away with it gets painful when you start allowing and infinite number of nested and\or's

Comment: Make sure to whitelist the phrases like **AND**, **OR**, the operators (>, <=, etc.), and any other SQL key words that you want to be dynamic.  That is the best way for SQL injection attacks.